# Running command on multiple files within multiple directories

Tags: shell, files, osx, directory

I want to run the command

```
python quast.py -o quast contigs.fasta
```

but I want to do this for multiple `contigs.fasta` files in multiple directories.

I'm running OSX.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the find command to help you run it multiples times. It should be something like:

```
find /your_dev_dir -name "contigs.fasta" -exec python quast.py -o quast {} \;
```

This runs the command on every file called `contigs.fasta` that is in `/your_dev_dir`, or a subdirectory of that directory, or a subsubdirectory recursively.